# How can I get Google to re-point its search entries to new domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, google

My main .com domain registration lapsed and when I went to re-register it, I found that a domain reseller service squatted it and I've lost access to it. As I wasn't terribly keen on spending money on funding scammers and the like, I registered a .co.uk domain under the same name.

Is there any way of getting Google to re-point all its indexed links to the new domain? It's been indexing my blog for a couple years now and while it's not too big a deal, I'd like to not have to start all over again. Also, searching for my site results in an old entry which is currently pointing at a "Apply for a Tax Break NOW!!!" page.

Answer (score 4):

Not really - you need to 301 the old address to the new, which you can't do now as they own it :(

If you registered your old domain with webmaster tools you can try telling google your site has a new home in the settings (not sure how this will work without a 301 though).

Answer (score 0):

If you own a copyright or trademark of the name, might be worth looking into re-claiming the domain legally.